# Custom Post Archive - display page 1 differently then subsequent pages

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post archive listing of publications.

The template generally works fine, but I'm trying to display the excerpt (actually a custom field called Abstract) for just the most recent publication. The rest would be the title/link only.

I thought I could do it with a i++ counting function, but each page starts the count over.

So, then I tried adding an if paged conditional on top of that. Template still works but does not recognize if its page 1 (I'm assuming, or else I'm just doing it wrong)

Relevant code is below

you'll see I tried assigning the variable $abstract to the custom field outside the loop first, then echoing it within the loop if it met the conditions of being page 1 and i=0 - otherwise it would be echoing an empty variable, in theory anyway.

I also tried adding the whole thing within the loop -  I've included both here but I did not actually have both going at once:

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var(‘page’) ) ? get_query_var(‘page’) : 1;
    if($paged == 1 ) {
         $abstract = get_field('publication_abstract'); 
    } else  { }

if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?> publist-<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h1 class="main_title">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
<?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a></h1>

<div class="entry-content">
<?php $paged = ( get_query_var(‘page’) ) ? get_query_var(‘page’) : 1;
    if($paged == 1 ) {
         $abstract = get_field('publication_abstract'); 
        if ($i == 0) { ?>
                <?php echo $abstract; ?>
                      <?php } } else { } ?> 

</div> 
</article>
```

I think I could do a custom query for the first one, then display the rest but I was trying not to mess with the pagination.

Another thing: I'm also adding a filtering function - by category, by date, etc. and don't want ANY filtered results to display an excerpt. So, when you land on the page, most recent shows the excerpt, but once you filter, none do. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds possible. Archive pages have a built in query they execute if you want to filter you can create a template for just that category such as `archive-{category}.php` or if your going to filter more information like described you should use.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_change_sort_order'); 

function my_change_sort_order($query){
    if(is_archive()):
       //Set the order ASC or DESC
       $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    endif;    
};
```

as you loop you can modify the output.

```
if (have_posts()) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

   <?php if($wp_query->current_post == 0): ?>
       //current_post is the index of the post within the loop
       // this will be your first post
       <?php echo $post->title ?>
       <?php echo get_field('publication_abstract'); ?>
   <?php endif ?>

    //this will be all other posts
    //just the title no excerpt 
    <?php echo $post->title; ?>

<?php endwhile ?>
```